# Instagram likes API only returns likes on your on media?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm using the :
`GET/users/self/media/liked` API from instagram

With the summary:

> Get the list of recent media liked by the owner of the access_token.

However, I only get the likes I have posted on my own media. 
Meaning, I have liked two pictures I have posted myself. Therefore, the API returns two links to my pics, nothing else.

However, I expected to get a list of ALL media I have liked, including the pictures my friends posted. Or this not possible?

Comment: Link to the API Im using : https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Comment: Is it sandboxrelated perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Your application is still in sandbox mode which has some limitation:

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users Data is restricted to the
> - 10 users and the 20 most recent media from each of those users Reduced
> - API rate [limits](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/)

Which means the API behaves as if the only users on Instagram were your sandbox users. To get out of Sandbox mode and these limitations, you need to [submit your app for review](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/).

Comment: Ok, but now I have two registered sandbox users, myself and a friend. But I still only get the likes posted by myself on my own media(which is only 2 so Im not running into the max limit)

Comment: Im been using the sampleproject from the instasharp library available under github https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp